# Can someone explain jQuery.sap.setObject?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

Why would I use [jQuery.sap.setObject](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.setObject) to set the value of a property in a object? Is not easier to simply write object.property = "value"? Can someone explain what is the use-case for jQuery.sap.setObject? In which situations do you find it to be useful? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it can set deep paths on sub-branches that don't exist.

Comment: Can you please explain what 'sub-branches' are dandavis?

Comment: you can set "obj.a.b.c.d" when `obj={};`, without first creating obj.a, then obj.a.b  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dandavis already mentioned it is just a convenience function to create deep nested objects with one call without overriding existing nestings. Especially in case of namespacing this can be useful.

It enables you to replace

```
var obj = obj || {};
obj.a = obj.a || {};
obj.a.b = obj.a.b || {};
obj.a.b.c = obj.a.b.c || {};
obj.a.b.c.d = function(){return "HelloUI5";};
```

with

```
jQuery.sap.setObject("obj.a.b.c.d", function(){return "HelloUI5";});
```

A use-case scenario can be found in [sap.m.library.js](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/library-dbg.js). Just search for jQuery.sap.setObject there.